# Elasticsearch query match one word

Tags: elasticsearch

if i have three rows like

```
name: "cat"
name: "cat is white"
name: "cat is black"
```

If i query filed name with string 'cat' using match or term query, get all three results.

How to get only name: "cat"?

```
GET animals/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "name": {
      "query": "cat"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on keyword field

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": "cat"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

term query performs case sensitive match. If you want case insensitive match you will have to use normalizer on keyword field